# Why can't I create directories under /root as a member of root?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, group

I've done the following:

```
sudo usermod -a -G root userA
sudo su - root
cd /
chmod 775 root
ls -aln
-- drwxrwxr-x.   6 0 0 4096 Sep 13 22:04 root
```

I can `cd /root` from my `userA`, but I can't make directories.

```
mkdir testing
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘testing’: Permission denied
```

For completeness:

```
id userA
uid=624981(userA) gid=624981(userA) groups=624981(userA),10(wheel),0(root)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your primary group is userA; try `newgrp root` first

Answer (score 0):

In order for the addition of the user to the group to take effect, you have to logout and relogin.